# Applying perspective divide on x and y only?

Tags: opengl, rendering

In the derivation of perspective matrix, z-value is shifted to w-value

[image: shifting z-value to w-value]

so that when perspective divide is applied to the result of matrix-multiplication with position values, the value of z can be preserved.

[image: perspective divide]

**Why can not hardware just apply z-divide on x and y value only?**

That will save several extra calculations that are done in rendering pipeline such as shifting w-value to z-value, compensation third row of perspective matrix with extra z-multiply because eventually, it will be divided by z-value etc.

Comment: "*In the derivation of perspective matrix*" Where is this matrix coming from? Because I don't see where the near/far planes are in this equation.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  updated the post to fix confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to extend on [@ybungalobill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55779959/2327517):

doing the division `z_clip / w_clip` is not strictly necessary if the only reason would be mapping near and far planes to specific values in NDC (-1 and 1 for default GL conventions). If the division was not carried out, we *could* use a different third row in the projection matrix, which basically could just implement a scale and an offset, so a simple linear function.

But using the division actually allows for **linear** interpolation of `z` in *screen space*.

If you don't do the division on `z`, you mathematically transform the data in a way that a triangle will be *curved* in the z dimension: (unless it is parallel to the image plane). Think about it: if you have some triangle which extents into the depth, the perspective distortion will have the effect that a point that lies exactly in the center of the 2D projection will **not** be the image of the center point in the real 3D input.

If you do the actual `z/w` division, you will get a hyperbolic mapping from eye space `z` to window space `z`, but that one can then be *linearly* interpolated - the primitives stay flat.

Here is a top-down view of eye space and window space for both cases:

[image: top down view of eye space and window space for hyperbolical and linear depth values]

The lines in the image shall represent rectangles (or triangles) in 3D. One one of them, the center point is marked. Due to perspective division on `x` and `y`, the  that center point is mapped much closer to the end point in the 2D image.But if you keep `z` linearly, the windows space `z` value of that point will still be at 50% between start and end `z` - which will not be on a straight line any more.

By also doing the perspective division on `z`, you will also move the `z` value much closer to the end point - by exactly that amount so that it lies on the straight line.

Because we want a very highly optimized depth test in hardware, being able to efficiently calculate the depth for a primitive at any point on the screen is very important. For example, the *hierachical Z test* (a.k.a *Hi-Z*) will try to reject parts of a primitive for a complete *tile* of pixels, and for that, calculating the maximum or minimum `z` value the primitive has *inside that particular tile* is much more efficient if the depth value can be interpolated linearly.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation.
If near to far clipping range is normalized to -1 to +1, the mapping stays linear and we don't do division on z, will the triangle still be curved in the z-dimension?

Comment: If you don't do the division on `z`, it will be curved, there is no way around that. If you linearly interpolate  `x/w` and `y/w` (and that is what the GPU does for each fragment), you also have to linearly interpolate `z/w`.

Comment: I am wondering where this curve is introduced? is it introduced when near to far clipping-plane range is normalized to -1 to +1 or somewhere else?

Comment: The depth range has nothing to do with that. This is just a geometric property of projective mappings by themselves. With a standard projection matrix and the correct perspective divide, you end up with  `z_clip (z_eye) = C * z_eye + D` (with `C` and `D ` from the third row of the matrix) and `z_ndc(z_clip) = z_clip / w_clip` and thus `z_ndc(z_eye) = (C * z_eye + D ) / (-z_eye) = -C - D / z_eye` which is a hyperbolic function, and inherently non-linear.

Comment: Changing the conventions for near and far plane position in NDC will not change anything on the formula itself, it will just lead to different values for `C` and `D`.

Comment: makes sense! 
How about, if for converting z_clip to z_ndc we don't divide z_clip by w_clip and we choose C and D of perspective matrix in such a way that it only does scale and offset. Then:
`z_clip = C * z_eye + D ` (with C and D from the third row of the matrix) 
`z_ndc = z_clip` which means 
`z_ndc = C * z_eye + D`

and bcz z_eye is not coming in denominator in any of these equations, the range will stay linear. (considering curve comes when z value is in denominator is any of the eqs)

Sorry if I didn't understand anything and pls correct me if I m wrong at any of the above steps

Comment: That was exactly what I talked about in the first paragraph of my answer. If you do that, you end up with the curved mapping, as in the _right_ image in my drawing.

Answer (score 2):

The perspective matrix you show will correctly project the vertices on the 2D image plane, but it will loose the depth information. The later is necessary for correct Z-buffering. Remember that it is the *z<sub>ndc</sub>* that is compared and stored into the depth buffer.

Therefore for correct hidden-surface removal that third coordinate is necessary, and the correct perspective matrix would be

```
*  *  *  *
*  *  *  *
0  0  C  D
0  0  -1 0
```

Where *C = -(f + n)/(f - n)* and *D = - 2fn/(f - n)*. Here *f* and *n* are the far and near clipping planes.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the post. The image I initially posted was causing confusion. Now, 1st image shown has derived perspective matrix, but my question remains the same, why can't we derive this matrix in a way that we ask hardware to only divide x and y by z?

Comment: @user2259784: the answer remains the same. We need the divided `z` coordinate for depth-testing, and we need the 3rd matrix row to scale it between the near and far planes.

Comment: @user2259784: Your post hasn't changed; the perspective matrix you're using is the same.